# How often (time between checks) does Postman check your collection for changes to commit to github?

Tags: github, postman

I have integrated github with my collection. In the Postman documentation it says postman often checks for changes and then commits those changes to your repo. Does anyone know exactly how often it checks for changes and if you can adjust the time between it checks for changes?

I checked postman forums and documentation and no luck.